# Show that this set function is a measure on a sigma-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

does anyone know how to prove this exercise?

Let $(Ω, A, μ)$ be a measure space and $f : Ω → [0, ∞]$ $A$-measurable. Show that the set function

$μ_f : A → [0, ∞] : B → \int_B fdμ := \int_Ωf · \mathbf{1}_B dμ$

is a measure on $A$.

I started showing that $μ_f$ of the empty set equals $0$. And then I tried to prove the $\sigma$-additivity property: $μ_f(\bigcup_{i=i}^∞A_i) = \sum_{i=i}^∞μ_f(A_i)$ but I couldn't.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other assumption on $f$ (for example $f \ge 0$, or that $\int_{\Omega} |f| \mathrm{d} \mu < +\infty$)? Without these assumptions you can't even say that $\mu_f$ is well defined!

Comment: No, there is not... Just that $f$ is $A$-measurable.

Comment: Are you considering positive measures or signed measures?

Comment: Just positive measures.

Comment: This means that a necessary condition for $\mu_f$ being a positive measure is that $f \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove that for disjoint $A_i$ the equality $I\Big\{x \in \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^\infty A_i\Big\} = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty I\{x \in A_i\}$ holds. Then Apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: By $I$ you mean the indicator function $\mathbf{1}$? That is the point, I don't know how to prove that equality holds for disjoint $A_i$. Could you help me?

Comment: $I$ is the indicator function, yes. Proving this equation is just using the definitions. If the indicator on the left is $1$, then $x \in A_i$ for exactly one $i$ (since the sets are disjoint). But then the function on the left is $1$ as well. If the indicator on the left is $0$, then $x \notin A_i$ for any $i$ and the function on the right is also $0$.

Comment: Ok yes thank you! And then if their intersection is not the empty set, then how do you use the monotone convergence theorem there?

Comment: You don't. The $\sigma$-additivity of measures only needs to hold for sets that are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Yes, true I didn't realize that. So is it not enough to prove that $I\Big\{x \in \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^\infty A_i\Big\} = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty I\{x \in A_i\}$ and then just substitute it into the integral and separate it as a sum of integrals? I don't see how to use the monotone convergence theorem here. Thank you

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem is necessary to interchange the summation and the integral.

Comment: Perfect now I understand it, thank you!